# Android MPAndroidChart getting partial Pie chart : retrieving data from server using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library for pie chart in my android application, using mysql server data. I used volley library to retrieve the data from server.

I can able to retrieve data json successfully:

```
com.example.bharat.plantnow D/ChartActivity﹕ Location Response: [{"treecondition":"Balanced","Count":"2"},{"treecondition":"Dieseased","Count":"1"},{"treecondition":"Healthy","Count":"4"},{"treecondition":"Imbalance","Count":"2"},{"treecondition":"Transplanted","Count":"1"}]
```

But In pie chart , I am getting only last value i.e "Transplated" with Count "1", remaining not able to display. Pl help me where I am getting wrong in CODE.

```
private boolean addData(){
       String tag_string_req = "req_location";

     showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_PIECHART, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                JSONArray jTreeList = new JSONArray(response);
                // boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");


                // Check for error node in json
                for (int i = 0; i < jTreeList.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject location = jTreeList.getJSONObject(i);

                    String treecondition = location.getString("treecondition");
                    Integer count = location.getInt("Count");

                    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
                       for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                        yVals1.add(new Entry((count), j));

                    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int j = 0; j < treecondition.length();j++)
                    xVals.add(treecondition);

                    //create pie data set

                    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1,"First pie chart");

                    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
                    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);

                    //add many colours

                    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
                        colors.add(c);

                    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
                        colors.add(c);

                    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                        colors.add(c);

                    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
                        colors.add(c);

                    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
                        colors.add(c);

                    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
                    dataSet.setColors(colors);


                    //instantiate pie data object now

                    PieData data = new PieData(xVals,dataSet);
                    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
                    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
                    data.setValueTextColor(Color.GRAY);


                    mChart.setData(data);

                    //undo all highlight

                    mChart.highlightValue(null);

                    //update pie chart

                    mChart.invalidate();



                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            hideDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

    return false;





}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure your code that I am showing below does not do what you expect it to do:

```
  String treecondition = location.getString("treecondition");
  Integer count = location.getInt("Count");

  ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
      yVals1.add(new Entry((count), j));

  ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

  for(int j = 0; j < treecondition.length();j++)
       xVals.add(treecondition);
```

I'll evaluate what this code will do in terms of the `PieChart`:

- Your first `for-loop` has as many iterations as specified in the `count` variable. Then you add the `count` variable to an `Entry`. This will result in each slice having the same value and being equally sized, completely independent of your data.
- Your second `for-loop` has as many iterations as the `String-variable` `treecondition` has characters. Then you always add that same string to your `x-values` array in each iteration. If you for example have a `String` "Horse", this will result in an `x-values` array of length 5 containing the `String` "Horse" five times.

If that is **not** what you expect your code to do, then I suggest you check your `for-loops` again.

**EDIT**:

I get it now. The issue is that your "count" variable is 1. This means only one `Entry` will be added to the chart - and therefore you can see only one `Entry`.

Adding more `x-values` alone will not create any more slices on the `PieChart` since there is no more data for the slices.

Comment: Exactly What I want. Its working for only one slice i.e my last iteration, but I want to show all of them. Pl suggest me.

Comment: Can you show an image of what the chart looks like?

Comment: Look at this link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oCnX38dLZ_S0lDeVdMU19IelE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yea but I also have [{"treecondition":"Balanced","Count":"2"},{"treecondition":"Dieseased","Count":"1"},{"treecondition":"Healthy","Count":"4"},{"treecondition":"Imbalance","Count":"2"},{"treecondition":"Transplanted","Count":"1"}]. Why it takes only last iteration.

Comment: Because you call `setData(...)` in every iteration and overwrite the previous data.

Comment: did anyone got the solution